# jsf 2.2, netbeans, ui:remove - Tag Library supports ... but no tag was defined for name: remove

Tags: jsf, netbeans, taglib, jsf-2.2

New Netbeans installation throws this error:

```
/index.xhtml @10,20 <ui:remove> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets, but no tag was defined for name: remove
```

Environment:

- Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528)
- Java: 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03 Runtime:
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_51-b13
- System: Mac OS X version 10.9.1 running on x86_64; UTF-8; de_DE (nb)

JSF page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:remove>throws an error</ui:remove>
    Hello from Facelets
</h:body>
```

Other ui tags do work.

To reproduce the error just run the new project Web Application wizard and insert an ui:remove tag. Can anyone reproduce this error?

Additional Information:

I updated Netbeans to "Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 7.4 Patch 2". Still the same exception.

The ui:remove do not throw an exception on a similar machine with an older OSX (10.8.5) and an older JDK (1.7.0_40). Rest same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounters this or similar strange problems with facelets like

> One or more resources have the target of "head", but no "head"
>   component has been defined within the view.

just change the javax.faces.jar to a current version. To do this:

**First:** find the "modules" folder from the glassfish installation. On my Mac it's

> /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/modules/

**Second:** find the javax.faces.jar and replace it with a current version (just search the net and download). In my case it is javax.faces-2-2-5.jar found at https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.5/

**Third:** don't forget to restart NetBeans